# .set label, . Vs. label: GNU AS

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

In the GNU Assembler, the current address is represented by the `.`

This makes it possible to set a constant/symbol and use it as if it was a label, for example:

```
.set offset, .
        .long 0x10

.globl _start
_start:
        # %eax should be 0x10
        movl offset, %eax

        # %ebx should be address of offset
        movl $offset, %ebx

        # Value at the address of offset should contain 0x20
        movl $0x20, offset
```

The above code behaves exactly the same as if `offset` was a label instead of a symbol.

Is there any case where the above does not hold true, or is a `label:` really just a shorthand for `.set label, .`?

Comment: Unlike a label you can `.set` something more than once and it will retain its last value.

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question. I've never seen anyone do this before. In short, yes, they are a little different. Here are a couple cases:

#### Local labels

This works:

```
// Local label:
    movq $2, %rax
1:
    decq %rax
    // Branch to preceding local label 1
    jg 1b
```

But this doesn't:

```
// Test the same thing with set:
    movq $2, %rax
.set 1, .
    decq %rax
    // Branch to preceding local label 1
    jg 1b
```

gcc emits: `Error: expected symbol name` because symbol names cannot start with numbers. For more information on symbol names, see the [binutils docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#index-local-symbol-names).

#### Multiple definitions

When you have two or more definitions using the same symbol name, labels behave differently. The docs say that the first label overrides all other labels, but in practice, your compiler won't even let you do this, even if the `.set` pseudo-op is used later. On the other hand, `.set` will let you assign the same symbol multiple times, but when a label is used of the same name, the symbol's value can no longer be altered after that. The label seems to make the symbol "read-only."

When using `.set` multiple times, it is always the most recent value or, if it hasn't been set yet, the next available value.

Let's say we have the following line to insert somewhere:

```
remote: jmp retval
```

```
jmp remote

//// If inserted here, the program returns -1

// Return -1
.set retval, .
    movq $-1, %rax
    jmp exit

//// If inserted here, the program returns -1

// Return 1 (also works as a label since we don't try to set it again after this)
.set retval, .
    movq $1, %rax
    jmp exit

//// If inserted here, the program returns 1

exit:
```

If you want to make sure that you aren't re-using a symbol defined earlier, use `.eqv` or `.equiv`.

#### And speaking of shorthand: The assignment operators

The `=` and `==` operators can also be used to set symbol values. See [Setting Symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Setting-Symbols.html#Setting-Symbols).

```
// This...
a=.
// ... is equivalent to
.set a, .
// ... or this (since .set and .equ are synonymous)...
.equ a, .

// And this...
a==.
// ... is equivalent to...
.eqv a, .
```

For an example of this being <strike>ab</strike>used, see this [code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132558/i-double-the-source-you-double-the-output/197964#197964).